# GAE - Deployment Error: "AttributeError: can't set attribute"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment

When I try to deploy my app I get the following error:

```
Starting update of app: flyingbat123, version: 0-1
Getting current resource limits.
Password for avigmati: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 125, in 
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 121, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4062, in 
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4053, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2543, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3810, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3006, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2995, in UpdateVersion
    self.options.max_size)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2122, in DoUpload
    resource_limits = GetResourceLimits(self.rpcserver, self.config)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 355, in GetResourceLimits
    resource_limits.update(GetRemoteResourceLimits(rpcserver, config))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 326, in GetRemoteResourceLimits
    version=config.version)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 379, in Send
    self._Authenticate()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 437, in _Authenticate
    super(HttpRpcServer, self)._Authenticate()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 281, in _Authenticate
    auth_token = self._GetAuthToken(credentials[0], credentials[1])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 233, in _GetAuthToken
    e.headers, response_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.reason = args["Error"]
AttributeError: can't set attribute
2012-04-25 19:30:15 (Process exited with code 1)
```

The following is my app.yaml:

```
application: flyingbat123
version: 0-1
runtime: python
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no
```

It seems like an authentication error, but I'm entering a valid email and password. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i create new google appengine acc and my app uploaded succeful.
but under the old account, I still can't deploy.

Comment: Maybe your old account is needs to be unlock using captcha, try unloading it at https://www.google.com/a/google.com/UnlockCaptcha

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem.
I'm using 2 factor authentication for my google account, so I previously had to enter a application specific password to deploy apps to GAE. If I entered my normal google password I got the `AttributeError: can't set attribute` error. However when I created an [application specific password](https://www.google.com/accounts/IssuedAuthSubTokens) and used it, it worked

Comment: I confirm this, I have 2 level auth and creating an application specific password solves the problem.

Comment: +1.  It was the two factor authentication (needs SMS code) that seems to block it.  After generating the application specific password as suggested, my app successfully uploaded.

Comment: or even better: use the new `--oauth2` option.

Answer (score 7):

The error message indicates that there is a bug in our SDK. Because of this bug, you can not see the reason of the failure. However, this code block is called only when the authentication request ends up with 403 HTTP error.

You can temporary tweak the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py as follows to see the actual reason(add `logger.warn(body)` line).

```
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
  if e.code == 403:
    body = e.read()
    # Add a line bellow to see the actual error
    logger.warn(body)
    response_dict = dict(x.split("=", 1) for x in body.split("\n") if x)
    raise ClientLoginError(req.get_full_url(), e.code, e.msg,
                           e.headers, response_dict)
  else:
    raise
```

Once if you find the reason, this issue must be much easier to solve. After you solve the problem, I'd appreciate it if you could create an issue about this mysterious error message in [our issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list)?

Answer (score 2):

I know this doesn't answer the OP question, but it may help others who experience problems using `--oauth2` mentioned by others in this question.

I have 2-step verification enabled, and I had been using the application-specific password, but found it tedious to look up and paste the long string every day or so. I found that using `--oauth2` returns

`This application does not exist (app_id=u'my-app-id')`

but by adding the `--no_cookies` option

`appcfg.py --oauth2 --no_cookies update my-app-folder\`

I can now authenticate each time by just clicking [Allow access] in the browser window that is opened.

I'm using Python SDK 1.7.2 on Windows 7

*NOTE: I found this solution elsewhere, but I can't remember where, so I can't properly attribute it. Sorry.*

.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after inserting logger.warn(body), I get this:
`WARNING appengine_rpc.py:231 Error=BadAuthentication
Info=InvalidSecondFactor`

The standard error message could have been more helpful, but this makes me wonder if I should not use an application specific password?

Comment: I have now generated an application specific password and then it works!

Comment: This happens when 2-step verification is on. A passwrod could be generated at https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthConfig

Answer (score 1):

Add the --oauth2 flag to appcfg.py update for an easier fix

Answer (score 0):

This also happens if your `default_error` value overlaps with your `static_dirs` in `app.yaml`.