# Trouble with Google appengine id

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I successfully launched an app locally on the local host

When I deployed to the appengine I got an error.

com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=my_id&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'my_id').

For some reason the ID given in the error has u and a space appended in the beginning

I doubled checked the application exists and succesfuly uploaded the app from another computer

Comment: Does one of the answers of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039200/this-application-does-not-exist-app-id-xxx help?

Comment: the u just means unicode.  Have you actully created an appengine Application through the appengine web interface with the id that you are using ?

Comment: Yes I created the app and ran it from another computer

Comment: Hello VonC it seems it is the same problem but I am not fluent with the command line so I need step by step instructions.

Comment: @RubberDuck which solution from the one listed in that other question do you think applies here?

Comment: VonC. Perhaps the one with the no cookies flag although .py implies python doesn't it?

Comment: @RubberDuck what IDE are you using for your GoogleApp? Eclispe? Komodo?

Comment: VonC I am using eclipse juno, I copied the IDE files to another computer and launched successfully. It must be something on this computer can you still advise?

Comment: @RubberDuck following http://stackoverflow.com/a/12181195/6309, look for a file `com/google/appengine/tools/admin/prefs.xml` somewhere in your HOME (or Windows profile if you are on Windows), and delete it. See if it works better.

Comment: VonC Thanks I tried and didn't find it. Perhaps because i'm on windows 7 and not on Linux. I didn't find many prefs.xml in my computer and checked them all to no avail.

Comment: @RubberDuck then look for an `appcfg.bat` of `appcfg.cmd`, and see of you cannot add the `--no_cookies` there.

Comment: VonC I found a file named appengine_launcher.bat. It had this line      @"%~dp0"\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe %*

Comment: @RubberDuck that doesn't look like a script which would use `appcfg.py` command. Could you check for any file containing `appcfg.py` ?

Comment: VonC thanks for the effort. I found the file it's huge. Does the python stuff interfere with the java stuff?

Comment: @RubberDuck no, but that python script is used for upload. I am not sure how it is invoked, but the solution would be to make sure it is called with the `--no_cookies` option. What is the full path of that file?

Comment: VonC the path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the solutions I can find (like "[This application does not exist `(app_id=xxx)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039200/this-application-does-not-exist-app-id-xxx)", or "[GAE - Deployment Error: “`AttributeError: can't set attribute`”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12750238/6309)") mention running `appcfg.py` with the `--no_cookies`

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py

 appcfg.py --no_cookies update my-app-folder\
 # or (2-steps verificatio enabled)
 appcfg.py --oauth2 --no_cookies update my-app-folder\
```

If the project contains Java7 classes, you need to add the `--use_java7` option, as shown in the question "[Failed to deploy to Google App Engine because `--use_java7` flag has not been set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13849112/6309)".

---

While you can run appcfg from the GAE installation path, the page "[Using the Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse)" mentions (at the bottom of the page):

> Some features of the App Engine Java SDK tools are only available by running the tools directly from the command line. If you have installed the SDK using Eclipse, you can run these tools from the Eclipse plugin installation directory.
>
> The SDK is located in your Eclipse installation directory, under `plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_VERSION/`, where `VERSION` is a version identifier for the SDK.
> In this directory is the **`appengine-java-sdk/bin/`** subdirectory containing the tools.

Comment: Found the file. Don't know where to add the code. is it next to this                 OAUTH_CLIENT_EXTRA_PATH_SCRIPTS = '(appcfg|bulkloader)'               like this?                                        OAUTH_CLIENT_EXTRA_PATH_SCRIPTS = '(appcfg|no_cookies)'

Comment: @RubberDuck I suppose it should be at the Launcher level, as mentioned in https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5359. I don't think modifying `OAUTH_CLIENT_EXTRA_PATH_SCRIPTS` would change the options passed to `appcfg.py`.

Comment: Thanks. I ran the first command in the appropriate directory on the command line thus: cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py enter then appcfg.py --no_cookies update my-app-folder\                                   This time the deploy process started but I'm getting this error     java.lang.RuntimeException: The application contains Java 7 classes, but the --use_java7 flag has not been set.  Is this a new question?

Comment: @RubberDuck I would recommend a new question, yes. I am looking into it right now. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848495/failed-to-deploy-to-google-app-engine-because-use-java7-flag-has-not-been-set before asking a new question

Comment: @RubberDuck I have edited the answer for making that option `--use_java7` visible.

Comment: Still got problems with the java flag posted question in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944620/how-to-set-use-java7-flag-for-googleappengine